# Not able to start jenkins after changing the home directory in centos7

Tags: jenkins

I am currently working on the devops project where we wanted to set the jenkins.

I have a jenkins instance which is already up and running on centos 7(AWS EC2 machine).

Jenkins Installation:

```
sudo wget -O /etc/yum.repos.d/jenkins.repo https://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat-stable/jenkins.repo
rpm --import https://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat-stable/jenkins.io-2023.key

sudo yum upgrade
sudo yum install java-11-openjdk
sudo yum install jenkins
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo yum install git
alternatives --config java
    → select java-11-openjdk.x86_64
```

It has the home diretory in : `/var/lib/jenkins`

I have followed the below steps to copy these to new area:

The jenkins version: 2.414.1

```
systemctl stop jenkins
mkdir /jenkins_home
cd /jenkins_home
cp -prv /var/lib/jenkins/ .
All permissions have been updated
systemctl edit jenkins
updated the `Environment="JENKINS_HOME=/home/jenkins_home/jenkins"`
```

After this I have started the jenkins: `systemctl start jenkins`

It is not starting and when I checked the log there is: `/home/jenkins_home/jenkins is not a directory` error

Can anyone please help on this?

Thanks in advance

I wanted this to be started smoothly, but it throws the above mentioned error

Answer (score 0):

`JENKINS_HOME` must be set to the directory where Jenkins is located. It appears you have that at `/jenkins_home`, off the root ("`/`"). That's NOT `/home/jenkins_home`.

`/home/jenkins_home/jenkins` is not a directory, it's the fully qualified name of a file.

A FIX:

`updated the ENVIRONMENT="JENKINS_HOME=/jenkins_home"`

Comment: I Have updated the same but it shows the same error while starting

Comment: Should ENVIRONMENT  uppercase? Did you `sudo systemctl edit jenkins`? And did you restart service?

Comment: Yes, I have done the same